# Setting relative classpath for BIRT POJO Datasource in .rptdesignfile

Tags: birt, pojo

[image]In the .rptdesign file when the"pojoDataSetClassPath" property is set to an absolute path , the report gets generated successfully.However when it is set to a relative path, the data from the data-source is not passed to the report thus the report has no data in it.

**For example:**
When i set the property value to the absolute path(C:\jars\Abc.jar) in .rptdesign file, report gets generated successfully.

```
<property name="pojoDataSetClassPath">C:\jars\Abc.jar;</property>
```

However when i set the property value to the relative path(./jars/Abc.jar), report does not contain any data.

```
<property name="pojoDataSetClassPath">./jars/Abc.jar;</property>
```

Can anyone please suggest a correct way to set the relative classpath , thus helping in picking the right pojodatasources.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: did u find a solution to this ? I am facing the same issue where I am not able to reference a Java class from my designer.